# How can Apache IoTDB monitor new data and transport through different platforms?

Tags: migration, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I am still getting to know Apache IoTDB, and I learned that IoTDB can generate real-time monitoring of new data and then transport them to other systems or platforms. However, I am not sure how IoTDB achieve this, can anyone tell me is this be completed by subscription or listen of IoTDB, or by other ways?

how to deal this question,someone help please

Answer (score 0):

You can see if trigger in Apache IoTDB can meet your need. Triggers provide a mechanism to monitor changes for time series data. With user-defined logic, functions such as alarm and data transport can be completed.

IoTDB allows users to dynamically register and uninstall triggers without starting or stopping the server during registration and uninstallation. You can also choose BEFORE INSERT or AFTER INSERT mode for trigger timing. The type of trigger can also be specified through the SQL statement when registering.